# McAfee blocking PDFs

Tags: adobe-acrobat, blocking

I'm running Windows XP SP3, with Adobe Reader 10.1.3. I also have McAfee.

I have always been able to open PDFs in Adobe Reader with no trouble. Now, all of a sudden, I can't.

If I turn off McAfee real time scanning and firewall, then the PDFs open just fine. As soon as McAfee is enabled, they won't open. It does this for all PDFs.

How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't have the time to properly troubleshoot, but try disabling Protected Mode in the General preferences within Adobe.  If that does not work, disable Javascript within Adobe as well.

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDFs with a different viewer?

Comment: add an exception, and/or adjust the settings on McAfee, so the default action isn't to block pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the problem. The Buffer Overflow function in McAfee had to be turned off before Adobe Reader would work. Now it works fine. Question is, why did this start happening only recently? McAfee always worked with Reader before...

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows 10, and figured out that McAfee firewall was causing the problem.  I went to "Intrusion Detection", checked off "Use Intruder Protection", and then checked "Basic--Detect activities that are very likely to be attacks. (Recommended)".  Immediately I could open Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat DC, which would not open before.